# Array Question related to both HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple bit of code. When the user chooses Others, an `<input type=text>` should appear.

But it only works when there is only one value selected.

Users can randomly add in the same `select` type, so the code can't be changed. For what I know, in javascript need to use `foreach`.

So my question is, how to let each of the `<input type=text>` appear in EACH of the `select` elements instead of it only appearing in the first one.

```js
function Pack(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('otherpack');  
 if(val=='others')
   element.style.display='block';
 else  
   element.style.display='none';
}
```

```html
<select name="Type[]" onchange='Pack(this.value);' required>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option> 
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>    
<option value="others">Others</option>                          
<input type="text" name="othermethod[]" id="otherpack" style="display:none"/>
</select>

<select name="Type[]" onchange='Pack(this.value);' required>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option> 
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>    
<option value="others">Others</option>                          
<input type="text" name="othermethod[]" id="otherpack" style="display:none"/>
</select>

<select name="Type[]" onchange='Pack(this.value);' required>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option> 
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>    
<option value="others">Others</option>                          
<input type="text" name="othermethod[]" id="otherpack" style="display:none"/>
</select>
```

Comment: `id` must be **NOT** repeated in the whole document.

Comment: User can randomly add in the same Select type, so the code cant be change. For what i know, in javascript need to use foreach.

Comment: Read [The W3 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) [...] `id = name [CS] This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.`

Comment: You are not checking element for undefined, always check a function returns what you expect it to return.  All id's must be unique and cannot be used for more than one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/am5ef67v/) is my solution:

```
function Pack(v) {
  var inputBox=v.nextSibling;
 var selectedValue=v.options[v.selectedIndex].value;
 if (selectedValue=="others") {
    inputBox.style.display='block';
 } else {
    inputBox.style.display='none';
 }
}
```

This should be the most stable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to make `change` events into javascript side instead of making it in `HTML`..

As suggested it is not good to use `input` inside `select` so make input outside of select box..

```js
const selectBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('select');

function Pack(select) {
  const selectedInput = select.nextElementSibling;
  if(select.value === 'others')
    selectedInput.style.display='block';
  else  
    selectedInput.style.display='none';
}

selectBoxes.forEach(select => {
  select.addEventListener('change', Pack.bind(this, select))
})
```

```html
<select name="Type[]" required>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option> 
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>    
<option value="others">Others</option>                          
</select>
<input type="text" name="othermethod[]" id="otherpack" style="display:none"/>

<br>
<br>
<select name="Type[]"  required>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option> 
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>    
<option value="others">Others</option>                          
</select>
<input type="text" name="othermethod[]" id="otherpack" style="display:none"/>

<br>
<br>
<select name="Type[]" required>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option> 
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>    
<option value="others">Others</option>                          
</select>
<input type="text" name="othermethod[]" id="otherpack" style="display:none"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving them unique `id`s? if you wanna have the same identifier in different elements, maybe use the class attribute instead.

Hope it helps, good luck !

edit: actually, now I see you're calling them with an `id` that isn't unique. Give **each** of the text-inputs their own `id` and it should work

`id`s are meant to be unique in the code, so whenever you call your function it assumes that there is only one element with that `id`

Answer (score 0):

`id` attributes should have unique values, so your selector will always select the first match.

Secondly, `input` elements are not allowed to be children of `select` elements. `select` elements can only have [`optgroup` or `option` elements as children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Technical_summary)

It is also best practice to attach listeners via JavaScript code instead of `onchange` attributes. You can listen at the document level (["event delegation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)) to avoid repeating several listeners (one per `select` element).

Here is how it could work:

```js
function Pack(e){
    let select = e.target;
    if (select.name !== "Type[]") return;
    let element = select.nextElementSibling; // this finds the INPUT element
    element.style.display = select.value === "others" ? "block" : "none";
} 

document.addEventListener("change", Pack);
```

```html
<select name="Type[]" required>
  <option value="Orange">Orange</option> 
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>    
  <option value="others">Others</option>                          
</select>
<input type="text" name="othermethod[]" style="display:none"/>

<br>
<select name="Type[]" required>
  <option value="Orange">Orange</option> 
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>    
  <option value="others">Others</option>                          
</select>
<input type="text" name="othermethod[]" style="display:none"/>

<br>
<select name="Type[]" required>
  <option value="Orange">Orange</option> 
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>    
  <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="othermethod[]" style="display:none"/>
```